# How to create keyboard shortcut for a command of developer tool in firefox?

Tags: firefox, screenshot, shortcut

I need to use Firefox developer tool command line to take screenshot at fixed time interval. The special command I need to use is `'screenshot --chrome'`, I wonder if I can create a keyboard shortcut for this.

If possible, how can I implement the fixed time interval function?